# My iOS app receive push notifications from firebase only when "test on device"

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification

I am trying to use Firebase for push notification in my iOS app. I followed the "set up an iOS client" guide from Firebase. And I found that my iOS app can not receive a notification when I send a message using target (user segment) from Firebase console. However, I can receive it when I use "Test on device" feature where I entered the FCM Registration Token of my iOS app.

Any idea why this could happen and how to fix it.

Thank you

Comment: That's exacly what is happening to us. Only working in "Test on device"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Firebase Cloud Messaging provides two ways to target a message to multiple devices:
Topic messaging, which allows you to send a message to multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic.
Device group messaging, which allows you to send a single message to multiple instances of an app running on devices belonging to a group.
-- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-multiple --"

Perhaps, with new firebase projects, it is impossible to send notification to all devices without define device group or topic messaging. I hadn't to configure those things in my previous apps.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase takes a while to propagate the Token across their servers, so the solution is just to wait a bit (minutes) and you will receive the notification both ways

Answer (score 0):

It was happening for one of our projects. FCM was only working with test device id or if the user subscribes to a topic.

We ended up making a new Firebase account and changed Firebase service files.
After this, FCM started working as expected without any other change.